# What is causing this "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named ___" exception?

Tags: java, xml, google-app-engine, jpa, gradle

I've been trying to work this one out for a couple of days now but none of the many things I have tried work!

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for
>   EntityManager named user

I have seen conflicting reports on where exactly persistence.xml should be located - are either of the places I have it below correct?

Apparently the causes of this error could be that I have persistence.xml in the wrong place (I don't think I do), that the persistence provider jar is not in the class path (I think it is), or that my dependencies aren't right (which I'm guessing it is, but can't tell what!)

[image: Location of my persistnece.xml]
Contents of persistence.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

<persistence-unit name="user">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

    <class>main.java.Account.User</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:google:mysql://grade-me:datastore/grademe?user=root"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5"/>
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

Grade build file:

```groovy
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.14'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.14'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.14'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.14'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.8.Final'
}

appengine {
    downloadSdk = true
    appcfg {
        oauth2 = true
    }
    endpoints {
        getClientLibsOnBuild = true
        getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
    }
}
```

I would be incredibly grateful for any help (please go easy on me if it's something stupid!) Thanks

Edit: Just thought I'd update to anyone stumbling across this that unfortunately I didn't manage to get hibernate working using any of these suggestions, and opted to use Objectify instead.

Comment: Your `persistence.xml` is located properly. Are you using entity manager ? Where and how do you initialize it ?

Comment: Thanks.
I initialise it in a method in a class in /java, using 

" EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("user");
        EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();"

Comment: Could it be something to do with where I placed hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.8.Final.jar ?

Comment: There isn't an "EntityManager" named "user". There is a persistence-unit named "user". Are you injecting the EntityManager via @PersistenceContext?

Comment: I would check and make sure the hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.8.Final.jar is in the right place.  It has to be visible to the app at startup.  I see it in your screen shot, but I am not familiar with andriod projects.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions everyone. If I try using @PersistenceContext (unitName = "user") annotation it throws a Null Pointer exception, so I assume, if the persistence.xml is in the right place, that it isn't seeing the hibernate jar

Answer (score 1):

Try changing hibernate-entitymanager to a compile dependency similar to hibernate-core. It might be a problem with the fileTree dependency.